# Get only available tags from a many to many relation with MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables with a many to many relationships; `media`, `relations`, and `tags`

```
      Media Table                      Relations Table                   Tags Table

| media-id | media-name |       | rel-id | media-id | tag-id |       | tag-id | tag-name|
-------------------------       ------------------------------       --------------------
| 1        | "Media 1"  |       | 1      | 1        | 1      |       | 1      | "tag 1" |
| 2        | "Media 2"  |       | 2      | 2        | 2      |       | 2      | "tag 2" |
                                | 3      | 1        | 3      |       | 3      | "tag 3" |
                                | 4      | 2        | 3      |       | 4      | "tag 4" |
                                | 5      | 1        | 4      |
```

I need a MySQL query that when a tag or tags are given, it will return all other possible tags combinations. Here are several examples.

#### Example 1

**Given:** `tag 1`

**Returned:** `tag 1`, `tag 3` and `tag 4`

**Because:** `tag 1` is tagging `Media 1` so it should return all of its tags (`tag 1`, `tag 3`, and `tag 4`)

#### Example 2

**Given:** `tag 3`

**Returned:** `tag 1`, `tag 2`, `tag 3`, and `tag 4` are returned

**Because:** `tag 3` is tagging both `Media 1` and `Media 2` so all of their tags are returned (`tag 1`, `tag 2`, `tag 3`, `tag 4`)

#### Example 3

**Given:** `tag 2` and `tag 3`

**Returned:** `tag 2` and `tag 3`

**Because:** `tag 3` tags *both* `Media 1` and `Media 2`, but only `Media 2` has `tag 2` so just it's tags are returned and `Media 1`'s tags are excluded

I've searched for something like this for a while, but I haven't found anything related with arcuate answers. The closest I was able to get to this was this query here:

```
SELECT `tags`.`tag-name`
FROM `tags`
WHERE `tags`.`tag-id` IN (
    SELECT `relations`.`tag-id`
    FROM `relations`
    WHERE `relations`.`media-id` IN (
        SELECT `relations`.`media-id`
        FROM `relations`
        WHERE `relations`.`tag-id` IN (
            SELECT `tags`.`id`
            FROM `tags`
            WHERE `tags`.`tag-name` IN ('tag 1')
        )
    )
)
```

This works great, maybe not the most effective, but I can understand it.

The only issue with this is if I were to run it on Example 3, it would return all the tags, instead of excluding tags from `Media 1`.

Is there a way that I could change my MySQL query to do this?

Comment: "Media 1" is also not tagged with "Tag 4".  Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, sorry, I edited by tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution to your problem involves multiple joins between the tables and aggregation, like this:

```
select t2.tag_name
from tags t
inner join relations r on r.tag_id = t.tag_id 
inner join media m on m.media_id = r.media_id 
inner join relations r2 on r2.media_id = m.media_id
inner join tags t2 on t2.tag_id = r2.tag_id
where t.tag_name in ('tag 2', 'tag 3')
group by t2.tag_name
having count(distinct t.tag_id) = 2
```

This:

```
('tag 2', 'tag 3')
```

is the list of the tags that you want the query to fetch the results.
And the number on the right side of the condition in the HAVING clause:

```
count(distinct t.tag_id) = 2
```

is the number of the items in that list.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=70d888f0f56fe393f473e513db3af3cf).
In the case of only 1 queried tag the code can be simplified to:

```
select t2.tag_name
from tags t
inner join relations r on r.tag_id = t.tag_id 
inner join media m on m.media_id = r.media_id 
inner join relations r2 on r2.media_id = m.media_id
inner join tags t2 on t2.tag_id = r2.tag_id
where t.tag_name = 'tag 1'
group by t2.tag_name
```

Comment: Yes because you must rejoin relations and tags to get the results that you want. Check the demo in my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the tags that are not used for "media_id = 1", then `not exists` comes to mind:

```
select t.*
from tags t
where not exists (select 1
                  from relations r join
                       media m
                       on r.media_id = m.media_id
                  where m.media_name = 'Media 1' and
                        r.tag_id = t.tag_id
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks, could you explain `t`, `r` and,  `m`? `tags`, `relations`, and `media`?

Comment: So if `t`, `r` and  `m` are abbreviations, does this filter all the tag id that is for `Media 1`? If so, I'm not sure how'd I'd Implement this into my query because I never input `Media 1`, not tag names.

Comment: @JackStoller  . . . `t`, `r`, and `m` are table aliases, a fundamental part of the SQL language.  As for "Media 1", if you don't put it in the query, then I don't understand the question.

Comment: I never knew that, I'm still pretty new to MySQL. I can see many applications for that. Sorry if it's not clear. I have edited my question and added serval examples that should help.